# How to make multi login with sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharedpreferences

i had implement [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) to using sharedpreferences, it's work for one user but when i do the same just add any string like that code it's just work too however it's always go to MainActivity not to Activity target what i want.

See my code: **SessionManager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {

SharedPreferences pref;

SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

Context context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "SSA";

private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

public static final String KEY_PETUGAS = "petugas";

public static final String KEY_HOTEL = "hotel";

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void createLoginSession(String name, String hotel) {

    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.putString(KEY_HOTEL, hotel);

    editor.commit();
}

public void createPetugasSession(String petugas) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(KEY_PETUGAS, petugas);
    editor.commit();
}

public void checkLogin() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user_SSA = new HashMap<String, String>();

    user_SSA.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
    user_SSA.put(KEY_PETUGAS, pref.getString(KEY_PETUGAS, null));
    user_SSA.put(KEY_HOTEL, pref.getString(KEY_HOTEL, null));

    return user_SSA;
}

public void logOutUser() {
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}


public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username, password;
Button login;

AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);


    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if (user.trim().length() > 0 && pass.trim().length() > 0) {

                if (user.equals("admin_ssa") && pass.equals("ssa_rotary")) {

                    session.createLoginSession("Admin SSA", "Admin Hotel");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else if (user.equals("admin_petugas") && pass.equals("petugas_rotary")) {

                    session.createPetugasSession("Admin Bandara");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArrivedActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else if (user.equals("admin_hotel") && pass.equals("hotel_rotary")) {
                    session.createLoginSession("Admin SSA", "Admin Hotel");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HotelManagementActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed..",
                            "username or password is incorect", false);
                }
            } else {
                alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed..",
                        "Please enter username or password", false);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kode.kreasi.rotarybarcode">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".Utils.BaseApps"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/rotarylogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationMenuActivity"
        android:label="Registration"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EventMenuActivity"
        android:label="Event"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".ScanQRCodeActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ManualActivity"
        android:label="Manual Absent"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ArrivedActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HotelManagementActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CheckInActivity"
        android:label="Check In"
        android:parentActivityName=".HotelManagementActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SummaryActivity"
        android:label="Summary"
        android:parentActivityName=".HotelManagementActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TourActivity"
        android:label="Tour"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OnTheSpotActivity"
        android:label="@string/onthespot"
        android:parentActivityName=".HotelManagementActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</application>
```

I think my code it's simple, but it's not working with my mine because actually i'm new. Hope you reply guys, thankyou.

[See the gif](https://gph.is/2OzfnNt)
In the first time i put the user + pass is the right target activity, but when i close the apps it's back to MainActivity not the target Activity.

Comment: explain the input that you are using and the exact steps

Comment: thankyou for your respone, i'm has edited and put the gif in the link. let see.

Comment: well, it's asking for permission, you can upload the gif on Stack as well, so Kindly do this

Comment: sorry, my bad. lets see again, now i move it to giphy becasue the size more 2mb.

Answer (score 0):

Where are using **isLoggedIn()** method? I don't see any implementation for that.

**In the LoginActivity check for login with isLoggedIn() method**

```
if(isLoggedIn()){
   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Is Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationcontext(), SecondActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
} else{
   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: after you post that code, i write it. but it's same problem. nothing change. When i login, it's to target activity but when i click the backpress and start the app again it's just go to MainActivity

Comment: Apply the same logic in OnBackPress() Method also.

Comment: When i put logic onBackPress, it's not changed

Comment: Which is your first activity before Login Activity? Apply this logic there. Suppose you have a splash screen before your login screen. So do apply the logic in Splash Screen